# sqlite db creation + objective-c + cordova

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, cordova

I am creating an app in IOS with cordova 2.1.0 framework. I am doing following to create the db:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
//NSError *error;  
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:self.databaseFile]) {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    self.databaseFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"klb_db.sqlite"];

    [self createConfigTable];
} else {
    NSLog(@"fail to create database");
}


// to create config table
-(void) createConfigTable{

    NSString *createStmt = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS config (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,key text,value text);";

    // Open the database and or create it
    if (sqlite3_open_v2([self.databaseFile UTF8String], &databaseHandle, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE , NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"database created");

        const char *sqlStatement = [createStmt UTF8String];

        char *error;

        if (sqlite3_exec(databaseHandle, sqlStatement, NULL, NULL, &error) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"Config table created.");
        }
    }
    else{

        sqlite3_close(databaseHandle);
    }

    sqlite3_close(databaseHandle);

    return;
}
```

Then, in cordova index.html , i am trying to run a query in the db created above as:

```
dbName = 'Database';

//to insert username, password into db
db = window.openDatabase(dbName, "1.0", gAppConfig.dbMessage, 200000);

db.transaction(querySelectConfig, errorQuery);


//Get Messages from the DB
            function querySelectConfig(tx) {

                alert('select config')
                tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM "'+gAppConfig.configTable+'";', [], querySelectSuccess, errorQuery);
            }
```

In the function querySelectConfig(), the query is failing. Why is the query failing. Is the db creation process flawed in objective-c. And secondly, what is the utility of klb_db.sqlite file. When a new database is created, does it need to be blank. And how is .sqlite file created.

Answer (score 0):

Use core data, it will save you time

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html